# Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the connection

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

he jdbc jar file for ibm db2 as400 is at the location:

```
/confluent-4.1.0/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc\jt400.jar

I am trying to configure the source file from Json file 
{ 
"name":"SOURCE_NAME", 
"config":{ 
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
"tasks.max":"1", 
"topic.prefix":"TOPIC_NAME", 
"connection.url":"jdbc:as400://IP_ADDRESS:PORT;libraries=DATABASE;", 
"connection.user":"USER_NAME", 
"connection.password":"PASSWORD", 
"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", 
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter", 
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081", 
"log4j.logger.io.confluent.connect.jdbc":"DEBUG", 
"mode": "incrementing", 
"incrementing.column.name": "ID", 
"query": "SELECT * FROM TABLE", 
"poll.interval.ms": "60000", 
"batch.max.rows": "10000", 
"table.types": "TABLE", 
"plugin.path":"/confluent-4.1.0/share/java" 
} 
}
```

I am getting error

```
{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s): 
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the connection. (Connection refused (Connection refused)) for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:as400://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/DATABASE 
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: The application requester cannot establish the connection. (Connection refused (Connection refused)) for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:as400://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/DATABASE 
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

I had configured Connect sources for Microsoft SQL Server with success and configurations seem very similar. What could be going wrong here.

Comment: Your database isn't accepting connections... Not a connect issue.

Comment: Your AS400 database isn't on the port you specified, or isn't accessible on the IP address, or your host is blocked by a firewall (although that would usually lead to a connection timeout instead). Connection refused is a low level socket error, meaning that sending the initial SYN to IP_ADDRESS:PORT got an RST in reply.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Kafka-Connect doesn't come with AS400 support. If you need AS400 support , kindly add AS400  under db2 dialect in JDBC connector and rebuild the connector

Answer (score 0):

Right now Kafka-jdbc-connector(Confluent) does not supporting DB2 AS400/iseries.
if you want to work with db2 AS400, add '**as400**' in as400 dialect Providers, add dependecy '**jt400**' in pom.xml and load the "**com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver**" in "GenericDatabaseDialect" class before establishing connection.
Adding provider in DB2 Dialect

```
 public Provider() {
  super(Db2DatabaseDialect.class.getSimpleName(), "db2", "db2j", "ibmdb","as400");
}
```

Adding AS400 Jdbc driver in Generic Database Dialect

```
    try {
  Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  throw new SQLException("AS400JDBC Driver Not found");
}
```